# Lightning component doesnot show the recordID

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am trying to show the classic URL in the Lightning page using the lightning component. But the record ID doesnt show up in the component. The component and controller is like below

Component

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
      <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
   
    This is the Classic URL of the record https://test.my.salesforce.com/{!v.myRecordID}   
    
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    doInit : function(cmp) {
        var xyz = cmp.get("v.recordId");
        cmp.set("v.myRecordID",xyz);
    }
})
```

When I try to add this component in the record page

[image]

Not sure what is missing here

Comment: How are you calling doInit method ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I thought doInit is called when the page is loaded

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I did add `    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>` in to my component but it didnt help. I updated the component code

Comment: check my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to explicitly call the init handler and you do not have attribute defined

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
      <aura:attribute name="myRecordID" type="String"/>

  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>


   This is the Classic URL of the record https://test.my.salesforce.com/{!v.myRecordID}   

</aura:component>
```

The JS controller is

```
({
   doInit: function(cmp) {
    var xyz = cmp.get("v.recordId");
    cmp.set("v.myRecordID",xyz);
   }
})
```

You can also omit the attribute and the method just use the below code

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >

  This is the Classic URL of the record 
   https://test.my.salesforce.com/{!v.recordId}   

</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 4):

A simpler solution wouldn't require any JS actually as you would be able to access the `recordId` attribute simply like below:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >

    This is the Classic URL of the record https://test.my.salesforce.com/{!v.recordId}   

</aura:component>
```